# Analyzing pcap files with python/scapy - missing layers

Tags: python, tcp, layer, scapy

my boss wants me decipher pcap files and write the frames to a db. Since I like python I searched for a lib that will do the basic stuff and I found Scapy. My inital trying (on Windows) went well but now I ran into problems.

I loaded a test pcap file using:

```
pfile = rdpcap("test.pcap")
```

And I look at the single frames by:

```
pfile[123].show()
```

I compare the output, frame by frame, with the same file loaded into Wireshark (which I use as reference for testing).

While it matches for many frames there are other frames where Wireshark shows a TCP layer that cannot be seen in Scapy.

At this stage I think its me not understanding something, but what is it? can anyone give me a hint?

BTW: I'm using Python 2.7 and installed the binary packages for Scapy 2.3.1 and pcap 1.1 (Windows 7).

Comment: Wireshark is a quite an advanced packet analyzer hence its capable of showing the which protocol was used on that layer. While Scapy will only show you the fundamental layer's and some additional protocols.

Comment: So its not actually missing layers , its just not showing you which protocol was used on that layer. While the data is the same used by both the tools.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I wonder where is the additional information stored that Scapy is unable to decipher? is it in the RAW part of the frame? I need to find a way to decode it to get the source and destination ports ...

Comment: Ok the payload can be decoded as TCP layer and matches what Wireshark shows. So far so good, but how can I tell if a payload (or any string) is a valid TCP or UDP layer? with Scapy I can create those layers from any random string it seems,...

Comment: well that is what wireshark does it has a predefined templates that help it to identify those layers, which  scapy doesn't have .